# Find specific resource filtering by name - Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to make an extension that is able to find a specific resource loaded by the page, filtering by name and downloading it. The reason I want to do this is because I usually go to the network tab in the developer tools, filter the requests/responses, for example, looking for one with the word "foobar" in its name, and open the link in a new tab so I can download it (it's an xml file).

I was wondering if this could be automated with an extension, even if the word  used to filter is hardcoded.

I don't have any experience with chrome extensions, so I wondered if this could be done or if it's just not possible with the devtools api. In case it could be done, if you could give me some guidelines on how to make it I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: no extension api about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to access the information you need in an extension.

1. You can write a [Dev Tools extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools). In that case, you have access to `chrome.devtools.network` API which will provide you that information.

   This requires you to open Dev Tools and interact with your own UI there (such as an extra tab in Dev Tools).
2. You can go low-level and use [`chrome.debugger` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) to attach to a page like Dev Tools would. It's a complex topic, I'm just pointing you in that direction.
3. Since you rely only on filtering by name, not response itself, you can use [`chrome.webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) to intercept network requests and log those that interest you for processing. **This is probably simplest to do.**

Comment: Thank you very much for the details! that's exactly what I was looking for.